# How to add a datasource with encrypted password in WildFly Swarm with .war packaging?

Tags: java, datasource, wildfly-swarm

I am using the below configuration to add data source to my WAR in a WildFly swarm:

```
  swarm:
    datasources:
       data-sources:
         MyDS:
           driver-name: oracle
           connection-url: <my-connection-string>
           user-name: <my-user-name>
           password: <my-password-in-clear-text>
```

How can this be changed so that the password is encrypted and not in clear text?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working example for Oracle12 with SecureIdentityLoginModule:

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      <your-datasoure-name>:
        driver-name: oracle
        connection-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@<your-oracle-ip>:<your-oracle-port>:<your-oracle-sid>
        security-domain: myEncryptedDs
  security:
    security-domains:
      myEncryptedDs:
        classic-authentication:
          login-modules:
            myLoginModule:
              code: org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule
              flag: required
              module-options:
                username: <your-oracle-username>
                password: <your-encrypted-oracle-password>
```

With the following command you can encrypt your password (the two jar-libraries can be found in your created wildfly-swarm-war-File):

```
java -cp <your-path-to-wildfly-jars>\picketbox-4.9.6.Final.jar;<your-path-to-wildfly-jars>\logging-2017.11.0.jar:$CLASSPATH org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule <your-password>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implements `org.wildfly.swarm.spi.api.ConfigurationFilter`.
Your class will be called for each property of your file. You can change the value at the same time. Here an example how to decrypt your value. You must provide a key (jvm startup) to decrypt your value.

```
public class DecryptPropertyFilter implements ConfigurationFilter {

private EncryptionHelper encryptionHelper;

{
    try {
        encryptionHelper = new EncryptionHelper(System.getProperty("encryption.key"));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T filter(String key, T value) {
    if (value instanceof String) {
        String str = value.toString();
        if (str.startsWith("ENC(") && str.endsWith(")")) {
            try {
                value = (T) encryptionHelper.decrypt(str.substring(4, str.length() - 1));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For thorntail.

```
thorntail:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      myDS:
        use-java-context: true
        statistics-enabled: true
        driver-name: mysql
        connection-url: ${db.url}
        security-domain: mydbSecure
        jndi-name: java:/myDS
        check-valid-connection-sql: select 1
        valid-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker
        validate-on-match: false
        background-validation: true
        background-validation-millis: 10000
        use-fast-fail: true
        min-pool-size: 5
        max-pool-size: 10
        prefill: true
        flush-strategy: FailingConnectionOnly
        exception-sorter-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter
  security:
    security-domains:
      mydbSecure:
        classic-authentication:
          login-modules:
            default:
              module-options:
                username: ${ds.uname}
                password: ${ds.pass}
              flag: required
              code: org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule
        cache-type: default
```

This is how you would encode the password

```
public class EncodePassword {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String password = "password";
        String encode = encode(password);
        System.out.println("Encoded password: "+encode);
    }
    private static String encode(String secret) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException
    {
        byte[] kbytes = "jaas is the way".getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(kbytes, "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encoding = cipher.doFinal(secret.getBytes());
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger(encoding);
        return n.toString(16);
    }
}
```

The below is how you would decode the password.

```
public class DecodePassword {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String value = "5dfc52b51bd35553df8592078de921bc";
        try {
            System.out.println(decode(value));
        } catch (Exception io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static char[] decode(String secret)
            throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        byte[] kbytes = "jaas is the way".getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(kbytes, "Blowfish");
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger(secret, 16);
        byte[] encoding = n.toByteArray();
        //SECURITY-344: fix leading zeros
        if (encoding.length % 8 != 0) {
            int length = encoding.length;
            int newLength = ((length / 8) + 1) * 8;
            int pad = newLength - length; //number of leading zeros
            byte[] old = encoding;
            encoding = new byte[newLength];
            for (int i = old.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                encoding[i + pad] = old[i];
            }
            //SECURITY-563: handle negative numbers
            if (n.signum() == -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < newLength - length; i++) {
                    encoding[i] = (byte) -1;
                }
            }
        }
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decode = cipher.doFinal(encoding);
        return new String(decode).toCharArray();

    }
}
```

for more information regarding picketBox.

https://source.jboss.org/browse/PicketBox/trunk/security-jboss-sx/jbosssx/src/main/java/org/picketbox/datasource/security/SecureIdentityLoginModule.java?r=276